# Ler Numero Inteiro em Java

Tags: java, if, condição, else

Tenho um exercício em `Java` onde o programa deve ler dois números digitado pelo usuário e ele devera me falar qual o maior!

Nesse caso não tem como eu usar apenas `IF` né? Devo usar também o `ELSE` ?
Sim são exercícios de `DESVIO DE CONDICIONAL`

Comment: Com um `if..else` você consegue resolver o exercício.

Comment: nossa que cabeça minha esqueci do else if!Obrigada

Comment: Oi @CarolM postei o código, espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
 int a,b;

System.out.println("A :");
     a=entrada.nextInt;
System.out.println("B :");
     b=entrada.nextInt;
 if(a>b)
{
       System.out.println("A é maior com valor:"+a);
}else if(b>a)
{
       System.out.println("B é maior com valor:"+b);
}else
{
      System.out.println("Os números são iguais com valor:"+a);
}

}
```

Primeiro insere os dois números e após a entrada, compare usando if, else if e else...